# Overlapping Marker Spiderfier: when I click the marker it appears Uncaught TypeError even when I don't register the listener to OMS

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers, overlapping

I have a simple webpage that shows a map and several markers on the map. It is common to have some markers really close to each other or even at the same exact location and that's why I'm using OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier (OMS).

I load google maps api like this:

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_GOOGLE_MAPS_KEY"></script>

<script src="./static/markerclusterer.js"></script>

<script defer src="./static/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier/oms.min.js"></script>
```

and creating the OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier object goes fine:

```
markerSpiderfier = new OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier(map, spiderConfig);
```

I get the same error adding the click listener or not but when I add it, I do like below

```
markerSpiderfier.addListener('click', 
    function(marker, e){
        var id = marker.zIndex;
        var contentString = getContentString(id, title);

        console.log("spiderfier click listener");
        e.cancelBubble = true;
        e.returnValue = false;

        if (e.stopPropagation){
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
        }


        infoWindow.setContent(contentString);

        infoWindow.open(netbee.map, marker);
    });
```

Inside an ajax block (which I use to update data from server) I make a for with all the data and add the marker to OMS like this:

```
data.forEach(function (item, index, array) {
    console.log(item);

        var date = parseDateAndTime(item.date, item.time);
        var latLng = {lat: item.latitude, lng: item.longitude};
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: latLng,              
          icon: pin,
          title: date,
          map: map,
          zIndex: item.id
        });

        var cellPhoneFilter = document.getElementById("cellphoneFilter");

        macs[item.mac] = item.mac;
        if(cellPhoneFilter.value === '' || cellPhoneFilter.value === item.mac){
          markers.push(marker);
          markerSpiderfier.addMarker(marker);
          reads[item.id] = item;
          reads[item.id].date = parseDate(reads[item.id].date);
        }                       
      });
```

Every time I click one of the markers, I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.map.getStreetView is not a function
at w.OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier.c.F (PATH/static/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier/oms.min.js:15:86)
at _.ve.<anonymous> (PATH/static/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier/oms.min.js:11:256)
at Object._.A.trigger (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDmgIRqJeCmq7klM7ge3pBbN6WC4x3eTrI&:94:121)
at KT.handleEvent (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/27/3/intl/pt_br/marker.js:49:459)
at _.qf.Rd (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/27/3/intl/pt_br/common.js:191:417)
at _.Iv._.k.Ce (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/27/3/intl/pt_br/common.js:241:205)
at _.Iv._.k.kj (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/27/3/intl/pt_br/common.js:240:246)
at Object._.A.trigger (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDmgIRqJeCmq7klM7ge3pBbN6WC4x3eTrI&:94:121)
at Lt.<anonymous> (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/27/3/intl/pt_br/common.js:138:342)
at Object._.A.trigger (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDmgIRqJeCmq7klM7ge3pBbN6WC4x3eTrI&:94:121)
```

It seems to me that I don't have this street view function that OMS uses just to make sure it's not a street view map and that's why I get this error. But I don't know how to solve it since I already loaded google maps api. I tried to find the code of OMS and edit it myself to take it off and see if it works, but I only found the minified code of it. Any idea of what I could do?

PS.: I use MarkerClusterer, but I don't think it's the problem

Comment: If you believe it is an issue with OMS, use the non-minimized source to debug (rather than `oms.min.js`).  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The issue wasn't with OMS, but using the non-minimized source helped me to figure it out. I was actually sending the div that constains the map and not the object map. Names were quite similar and it took a while to see it